# I'm getting "Property 'router' does not exist on type 'SigninComponent'." while using this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']); in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have import :

```
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
```

and then I have used below line in my function inside component

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
/* Missing if you are using 'this.router.navigate' */   

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Answer (score 45):

You need to pass it inside the **`constructor`** as follows,

```
constructor(private router: Router){
}
```

Also make sure you have imported **`Router`** as follows

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: That give me error in constructor : Cannot find name 'Router'.

Comment: did you import import { Router } from '@angular/router';

Comment: I realized I also need to import router, after that constructor code works, and my code works, kudos, thanks for help

Comment: That did for me as well. Just importing was still giving the error.

Answer (score 2):

Import ActivatedRoute library from angular router.

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
```

Use following custructor

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }
```

And Call navigate method

```
this.router.navigate(['/page2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: Property 'route' does not exist on type 'Component'

Add Modules :
import{ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor (private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router){}
Code Implementation:

```
this.memberService.getmember(this.route.snapshot.paramMap
      .get('name')).subscribe(member=>{
       this.member=member 
          })   
  }
```