# How to use routerLink inside SVG path?

Tags: angular, svg, routerlink

Hello

Is there a way to make routerLink Angular 6 inside different elements of one SVG?

```
<svg  width="256.53mm" height="269.27mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 256.53 269.27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

 <g  transform="translate(22.348 -13.007)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".26458px">
    <path (click)="goBalises()" id="gauche" d="m142.13 129.55 90.991-30.211 0.92948 103.56-91.145-25.734z"/>
    <path id="haut" d="m83.534 104.61-28.726-91.47 103.57 0.75595-27.214 90.714z"/>
    <path id="droite" d="m69.467 174.31-91.088 29.916-0.59389-103.57 91.061 26.03z"/>
    <path id="bas" d="m130.05 190.78 29.533 91.213-103.57 0.15841 26.412-90.951z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

```
goBalises(){
    this.router.navigate(['/balises']);
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A way I found to do this is by adding a data attribute to the svg and dynamically assign the onclick event in Angular (notice the `data-link` in the svg instead of `(click)`, I also added a wrapper div but you don't necessarily need it, in that case, add the `#imageContainer` to the svg tag directly)

```
<div #imageContainer>
    <svg  width="256.53mm" height="269.27mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 256.53 269.27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

     <g  transform="translate(22.348 -13.007)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".26458px">
        <path data-link='balise' id="gauche" d="m142.13 129.55 90.991-30.211 0.92948 103.56-91.145-25.734z"/>
        <path id="haut" d="m83.534 104.61-28.726-91.47 103.57 0.75595-27.214 90.714z"/>
        <path id="droite" d="m69.467 174.31-91.088 29.916-0.59389-103.57 91.061 26.03z"/>
        <path id="bas" d="m130.05 190.78 29.533 91.213-103.57 0.15841 26.412-90.951z"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

And in the Angular component, you get the container div and check for all the element with a data-link attribute then bind the click event listener to whatever you want.

```
export class SvgImage {
    @ViewChild('imageContainer', {static: false}) container: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

    initLinks() {
        if (!this.container || !this.container.nativeElement) {
          return;
        }

        var links = this.container.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[data-link]');

        links.forEach(val => {
          var converted = <HTMLElement>val;
          converted.addEventListener('click', () => {           
            this.router.navigate([link]);
          });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement @carak's answer, it is useful to take into account what @Sajeetharan pointed out here: [I'm getting "Property 'router' does not exist on type 'SigninComponent'." while using this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']); in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879112/im-getting-property-router-does-not-exist-on-type-signincomponent-while/44879133)

"You need to pass it inside the constructor as follows,

```
constructor(private router: Router){
}
```

Also make sure you have imported Router as follows

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

"